# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code to join the values of selectbox and add them to the textbox

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ascuisines').on('change', function () {
       $('#cuisineslisting').val($('#ascuisines').val().join());
    }).trigger('change');
    $('#asfeatures').on('change', function () {
        $('#featureslisting').val($('#asfeatures').val().join());
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

and my HTML Code is Like

```
<input type="text" name="cuisineslisting" id="cuisineslisting">
<select name="ascuisines" id="ascuisines" multiple="" class="chosen-select-width" required="">
    <option value="" disable=""></option>
    <option value="African">African</option>
    <option selected="" value="American">American</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="featureslisting" id="featureslisting">
<select name="asfeatures" id="asfeatures" multiple="" class="chosen-select-width valid" tabindex="-1" required="" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="" disable=""></option>
    <option value="Delivery">Delivery</option>
    <option value="BYOB">BYOB</option>
    <option value="Brunch">Brunch</option>
</select>
```

I don't know what's wrong but I am getting an error in my console as 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of null '

And this is still working in both application & JSFiddle but it changed the complete CSS properties of the selectbox.

If I comment either `$('#cuisineslisting').val($('#ascuisines').val().join());` or `$('#featureslisting').val($('#asfeatures').val().join());` then the CSS gets activated perfectly.

Comment: What CSS are you talking about?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) documentation:

> In the case of select elements, it returns null when no option is selected and an array containing the value of each selected option when there is at least one and it is possible to select more because the multiple attribute is present.

Assuming that "none selected is okay",

```
var selected = $('#ascuisines').val() || [];
$('#cuisineslisting').val(selected.join());
```

(Which utilizes the fact that the short-circuit `||` operator yields the first true-thy value of the operands.)

Comment: One line: $('#cuisineslisting').val(($('#ascuisines').val() || []).join());